# probleme old python script

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.x

hello everyone I have a problem with a python 2.X script that I would like to run in 3X here is the error message can you help me

```
outfile.write(fixed.encode,"(utf-8)")
```

TypeError: write() takes exactly one argument (2 given)

Edit:

```
#Write the converted program in this folder:
print ("\n--Converted to TI-Basic code:--")
print (fixed)
print ("")
print ("Making output files: "+outname+".tib, "+outname+".8xp ...")

outfile=open(outname+".tib","w")
outfile.write(fixed.encode("utf-8"))
outfile.close()
```

the code and the new errore message : line 68, in main
    outfile.write(fixed.encode("utf-8"))
TypeError: write() argument must be str, not bytes

Comment: Share more details of your code. Before of it,  and after of it

Comment: Python 2 scripts cannot be run with a Python 3 interpreter. See [Porting Python 2 Code to Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/pyporting.html) from the Python documentation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Error "TypeError: write() argument must be str, not bytes" is because you are trying to write in byte data but you didn't specified opened the file in byte mode. If you want to write string into a file use `with` statement

```
with open(outname+".tib","wb") as outfile:
    outfile.write(fixed.encode("utf-8"))
```

If the fixed variable is `str` type then you can avoid the `encode('utf-8')` from the above code then the mode should be just `w`

Comment: _The Error "TypeError: write() argument must be str, not bytes" is because you are trying to write in byte data but you didn't specified opened the file in byte mode._ That is technically true, although it seems to me that there is no reason not to write the string directly. _If you want to write string into a file use with statement_ They should use a context manager, but it has nothing to do with strings.

Comment: @AMC yup, Although there is no problem with writing in byte mode. Because his fixed variable is byte object. This wll also work.

Answer (score 0):

That was probably caused by some rogue IDE autocomplete/Intellisense.

It should be:

```
outfile.write(fixed.encode("utf-8"))
```

So, the quotes got switched around, not related to Python 2.x - 3.x conversion at all.

Comment: Ho i'm sorry the original code was what have you said the new error message is :TypeError: write() argument must be str, not bytes

Comment: Then you don't need to `encode`: `outfile.write(fixed)`

Comment: Thank you very much for you answer the code run 
perfectly i'm very happy

Answer (score -1):

There appear to be missing parentheses in `outfile.write(fixed.encode,"(utf-8)")`, the code looks jumbled.

Your code could be cleaned up in a few areas, I made some quick tweaks for now.

```py
#Write the converted program in this folder:
print("\n--Converted to TI-Basic code:--")
print(fixed, end="\n\n")
print(f"Making output files: {out_name}.tib, {out_name}.8xp ...")

with open(f"{out_name}.tib", "w") as out_file:
    out_file.write(fixed)
```